# How to split varchar and looping it then merge to varchar with ' , ' separator

Tags: sql-server

i have data varchar like this
`'201,203'`

i want split and want get data from relation other table like this

| Code | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | room A |
| 203 | room B |

i want the result is varchar and split result with separators coma ', ' like this
`room A, room B`

Comment: Did you try `STRING_SPLIT` ?

Comment: Donot store data as csv. Think about your db design

Comment: *"i have data varchar like this `'201,203'`"* so is this a parameter, or stored in a table?

Comment: Also, please *don't* treat [so] like a free coding service; it is not, it is a Q&A site. Stating "I want" isn't a question, it's a demand. If you have a question great, ask one. Explain the problem you're trying to solve and the difficulty you're having solving it. If you've made attempts, then you might want to share that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first construct a function similar to this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION roomSplit (@roomCode VARCHAR(MAX), @separator VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @res VARCHAR(MAX)
    
    SELECT @res = STUFF((
        SELECT
        ', ' + roomNameColumn
        FROM
        STRING_SPLIT(@roomCode, @separator) AS SPLIT
        INNER JOIN roomTable AS R ON SPLIT.value = R.roomCodeColumn
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    
    RETURN @res
END
```

Then you call function that you have created by filling parameters with your data and your separator data.

```
SELECT dbo.roomSplit('203,201', ',')
```

Comment: If you are going to use `STRING_SPLIT` why not also `STRING_AGG`? Also OP didn't ask for an aggregtaed resultset.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL SERVER 2016, You can use `STRING_SPLIT` to split your varchar and `row_number()` to generate an "ordinal" column :

```
SELECT value as code, 'Room ' + CAST ( Row_Number() over (partition by code ORDER BY (select 0)) AS varchar) AS Name
FROM mytable 
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (code, ',') cds
```

In newer SQL Server 2022 an optional flag has been added to `String_Split` to include an "ordinal" column :

```
select value as code, 'Room ' + cast(ordinal as varchar) as Name
from mytable
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (code, ',', 1)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using SQL Server 2014 or lower:

```
CREATE FUNCTION funRoomSplit (@roomCode VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @res VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    DECLARE @Delimiter CHAR(1) = ','
    DECLARE @Pos INT

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @roomCode) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Pos  = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @roomCode)  

        SELECT @res = @res + Name + ', '
        FROM [dbo].[SampleTable]
        WHERE Code = SUBSTRING(@roomCode, 1, @Pos - 1)

        SELECT @roomCode = SUBSTRING(@roomCode, @Pos + 1, LEN(@roomCode) - @Pos)
    END

    SELECT @res = @res + Name
    FROM [dbo].[SampleTable]
    WHERE Code = @roomCode

    RETURN @res
END
```

Comment: i using 2016 sqlserver